# Script to Tar file in a specific Directory

Tags: unix, compression

I'm trying to write a Unix script that will go to a specific directory (/tmp/Sanbox/logs) and tar.gz all the log files in that directory and delete the original files that are older than 2 days. So far I have this but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #!/bin/bash

AGE_TO_COMPRESS="172800" # 172800 seconds = 2 days
LOG_FILES="export/home/H0166015/Sandbox/logs"

# Any file older than EDGE_DATE must be compressed
NOW=$( date +%s )
EDGE_DATE=$(( NOW - AGE_TO_COMPRESS ))

for file in $LOG_FILES ; do
    # check if file exists
    if [ -e "$file" ] ; then

        # compare "modified date" of file to EDGE_DATE
        if [ $( stat -c %Y "$file" ) -gt ${EDGE_DATE} ] ; then

            # create tar file of a single file
            tar -cvzf $file.tar.gz $file --remove-files
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for file in $LOG_FILES/* ; do`  ?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly is not working? Do you get an error? The script doesn't compress the files or is not deleting the old files?!